# How to install step flashing on vertical side wall such that roof can be replaced later?

Tags: roof, vinyl-siding, flashing

I have a vertical wall along the edge of a roof. The intersection is like the side wall of a dormer. Having both a new roof and vinyl siding installed.

My perception is that the Tyvek wrap would first be nailed to the side wall and that the TyveK wrap would go over the aluminum step flashing. But this means that the new roof must be installed before the new siding. Then the vinyl siding track would be nailed over the Tyvek and aluminum flashing. But that means that to replace the roof singles and step flashing that the siding would have to be removed.

Being optimistic that the vinyl siding will last longer than the roof shingles. Contractor is using a high grade of singles.

How should  the step flashing and track for the vinyl siding be install so that the roof can be replaced without disturbing the step flashing and vinyl siding?

Comment: Normally the step flashing is left when a roof is removed and the new roof is interleaved into it. If it's not salvageable the siding will have to be partially opened up. Why doesn't your contractor know the answer?

Comment: (1) Didn't ask contractor yet how he planned to do it. (2) I believe in trust but verify.